# Sumar valores de un arreglo bidimensional y arrojar su total PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Hay un metodo (array_sum) en PHP que me suma los valores de un arreglo bidimensional sin necesidad de recorrer el arreglo, pero en este caso requiero recorrer ese arreglo sin necesidad de usar este metodo para mostrar los valores por arreglo y su total.

Eje:

```
    $total = 0;
    $numbers = ["SUMA1" => [8,5,1,5], "SUMA2" => [2,2,5]];


    foreach ($numbers as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $valores) {    
         $total += $valores;
        }       
    }
echo "el total es: ".$total;
```

Al realizar el `echo` me muestra el total de ambos arreglos `('SUMA1', 'SUMA2')`, lo que no he podido lograr es que me imprima la suma por arreglo, es decir:

```
El total de 'SUMA1' es 19
El total de 'SUMA2' es 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
    $numbers = ["SUMA1" => [8,5,1,5], "SUMA2" => [2,2,5]];


    $i = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $value) {
        $arr = array_keys($numbers);//Puedes ignorar este paso, solo es para sacar las claves
        $parcial = 0;//Debes sacar el total por cada iteración y resetarlo al terminar
        foreach ($value as $valores) {    
         $parcial += $valores;
         $total += $valores;
        }
        echo 'El total de' . $arr[$i] . ' es ' . $parcial. '<br>';
        $i++;
    }
echo "el total es: ".$total;

?>
```

Te puse ahí unos comentarios de los que hace el par de líneas que agregué, saludos.

Comment: Excelente men, muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes seguir usando `array_sum`, del siguiente modo.

Te pongo una versión mejorada, en caso de que te interese tener también un total general.

También agregué comentarios al código para mayor claridad:

```
    $total=0;
    $tmp=0;
    $numbers = ["SUMA1" => [8,5,1,5], "SUMA2" => [2,2,5]];
    /*Los arrays se pueden diferenciar como clave/valor usando "as"*/
    foreach ($numbers as $k=>$v) {
        /*Si el valor actual es un array, significa que debemos sumar*/
        if (is_array($v)){
              /*Suma del array actual*/
              $tmp=array_sum($v);
              echo "La suma de $k es: $tmp".PHP_EOL;
              /*Lo agregamos a un total general, en caso de que interese*/
              $total+=$tmp;
        }
    }
echo "El total general es: $total";
```

La clave es leer ambos componentes del array original, preguntar si `$v` es un array y entonces aplicas `array_sum` si lo es.

El resultado sería:

```
La suma de SUMA1 es: 19
La suma de SUMA2 es: 9
El total general es: 28
```

Comment: Un método sencillo y funcional, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción puede ser utilizando `array_map()` junto con `array_sum()`.

Ejemplo:

```
$numbers = ["SUMA1" => [8,5,1,5], "SUMA2" => [2,2,5]];

// Obtenemos las sumas de cada uno de los array 
$sumas = array_map('array_sum', $numbers);

// recorrer y mostrar las sumas 
foreach($sumas as $key => $value) {
    echo 'La suma de '. $key .' es '. $value; 
}
// obtener y mostrar la suma general
echo 'La suma total es '. array_sum($sumas);
```