# Almacenar en un arreglo bidimensional en php la suma de dos arreglos bidimensionales

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de sumar 2 arrays bidimensionales en php posicion por posicion de manera que:

el primer array la primera fila es 2 4 8

el primer array la segunda fila es 1 3 5

el segundo array la primera fila es 1 -1 1

el segundo array la segunda fila es 0 1 -2

el tercer array tendria que 
dar la primera fila 3 3 9
el tercer array tendria 
que dar la segunda fila 1 4 3

No consigo realizar la suma, adjunto el código hasta el momento.

```html
<?php
$array15 = array();
$array15[0] = array(2, 4, 8);
$array15[1] = array(1, 3, 5);

foreach ($array15 as $claveFilas => $fila) {
 foreach ($fila as $claveColumna => $dato) {
 echo "$dato";
 }
}
echo "<hr>";
$array16 = array();
$array16[0] = array(1, -1, 1);
$array16[1] = array(0,  1, -2);

foreach ($array16 as $claveFilas => $fila) {
 foreach ($fila as $claveColumna => $dato) {
 echo "$dato";
 }
}

$array17 = array_sum($array15) + array_sum($array16);
?>
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163946/sumar-valores-de-un-arreglo-bidimensional-y-arrojar-su-total-php

Comment: No es mi caso ya que ahí suma todo lo de un array de golpe y todo lo del otro array de golpe y luego los suma. Lo que necesito es sumar la posicion [0][0] del primer array con la posicion [0][0] del segundo array, la posicion [0][1] del primer array con la posición[0][1] del segundo array etc. Saludos :D

Comment: En la suma de las dos primeras filas el resultado esperado de la segunda posición es 4+(-1) = 3, no es 5 como actualmente lo tienes

Comment: @ontimond gracias si ahora lo vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta probar con estas funciones, esta divido por partes para que entiendas mejor.

```
// Valida que los arreglos tengan el mismo tamaño.
function __val($a, $b) {

  $tam_a = count($a);   
  $tam_b = count($b);   

  if($tam_a != $tam_b) {
    trigger_error("ops! Los tamaños deben ser iguales.", E_USER_ERROR);
  }

}

// Suma los valores de dos arreglos.
function __sum($a, $b) {

  __val($a, $b);

  $c = [];  
  foreach($a as $i => $a_x) {     
    $b_x = $b[$i];    
    $c[] = $a_x + $b_x;
  }

  return $c;  
}

// Suma los arreglos contenidos en los arreglos bidimensionales.
function __sum__matr($a, $b) {

  __val($a, $b);

  $c = []; 

  foreach($a as $i => $a_x) {     
    $b_x = $b[$i];    
    $c[] = __sum($a_x, $b_x);
  }

  return $c;
}

$q = [[2, 4, 8], [1, 3, 5]];
$z = [[1, -1, 1], [0,  1, -2]];

print_r(__sum__matr($q, $z));
```

Comment: Probado y validado, gracias @ontimond!